# C# Window Form - How Can I Automatically Backup Database And Send it to Online Phpmyadmin Or On Email

Tags: c#, mysql, database-backups, mysql-backup

Good day! I'm being curious on how can I backup the database automatically and send to online phpmyadmin or send the databasefile to prefer email. We are developing our System using Intranet where we use CentOS as our server provider of Mysql & Phpmyadmin. I'm just thinking what if the server fail and the datas stored there are corrupted. That's worst case scenario for one system working on one place. :( Our System is made from C# Windows Form.

I need some ideas(or link if needed) to make some backup automatically that will be save whether in online Phpmyadmin or send the database file to my prefer email.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a web interface for MySQL, so you don't want to save to online phpMyAdmin but to an external MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on the [MySqlBackup.NET - MySQL Backup Solution for C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/256466/MySqlBackup-NET) introduce a tool (DLL) that can backup/restore MySQL database in C#.

MySQL Workbench is good for developers, but, when comes to client or end-user, the recommended way is to get every parameter preset and all they need to know is press the big button "Backup" and everything is done. Using MySQL Workbench as a backup tool is not a suitable solution for client or end-user.

Comment: I'm reading your reference right now sir. :) I'll mark your answer as "Answer" when I feel you gave a right answer to my problem. Thanks anyway :)